# Configuring Postman to submit an event to Google Analytics Measurment API

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up reporting to google analytics via http requests. I am of the understanding that this is done via the Measurment API.
As such I am trying to set up a basic example in postman with this url via POST

```
www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-xxxxx&api_secret=xxxxx
```

With the following body

```
{
"client_id": "x",
"events": [
  {
    "name": "offline_purchase",
    "params": {
      "engagement_time_msec": "100",
      "session_id": "123"
    }
  }
]
}
```

This appears to return a 403 error. What mistake am I making when setting this up?

Comment: I would suggest dropping the whole MP idea and just mimic your typical front-end tracking with no secrets required. 403 implies access issues.

Comment: Could you give me some more detail as to how I would send events to google analytics not using the MP api?

Comment: on this page, disable your adblocker, open the dev tools, go to the network tab, filter `collect?` and reload the page. You will see how this page does it without MP. Mimic it. Done.